# Implicit Function Theorem and Total Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I apologize in advance as this is rather roundabout. I have seen the Implicit Function Theorem (in a more specific case) stated as such

> Let $x=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m)$. Let $G(x, y): \mathbb{R}^{m+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a once continuously differentiable function around some neighborhood $N_\delta$ of $(x_0, y_0)$. If $G(x_0, y_0) = c$ and $\dfrac{\partial G(x, y)}{\partial y}|_{(x_0, y_0)} \neq 0$ then there exists a once differentiable $y(x)$ on some neighborhood $N_\varepsilon$ of $x_0$ such that
>
> 1. $G(x, y(x)) = c \; \forall x \in N_\varepsilon$
> 2. $y(x_0) = y_0$
> 3. $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_i} |_{x_0} = -\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial x_i}|_{(x_0, y_0)}}{\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y}|_{(x_0, y_0)}}$

I am hesitant accepting the third antecedent of the theorem. Assuming 1,2 are true. We have by chain rule
\begin{align}
0 &= \sum_{j=1}^{m} \dfrac{\partial G}{\partial x_j} \dfrac{d x_j}{d x_i} + \dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y} \dfrac{d y}{d x_i}\\
\dfrac{d y}{d x_i} &= -\dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^{m} \dfrac{\partial G}{\partial x_j} \dfrac{d x_j}{d x_i}}{\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y}}
\end{align}

This seems to be a much weaker result. **The question is**: Why does the left hand side of (3) have partial derivatives and not total derivatives? Further, why does it seem to be $\dfrac{d x_j}{d x_i} = 0$ for $i \neq j$ so that most of the terms of the sum are removed? I suspect it may have to do with [wrongly manipulating the chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio). Most proofs of the theorem that have been shown to me lack the detail and simply conclude (3) "by implicit differentiation."

Comment: In the implicit function theorem, the $x_i$'s are independent coordinates, so they don't depend on each other.  This is why $\frac{dx_j}{dx_i}=0$ for $i\not=j$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks, that was my suspicion. That seems a bit subtle to me. Is there anything in the theorem that should lead me to that assumption (or perhaps my statement of the theorem is incomplete)?

Answer (score 1):

In the implicit function theorem, you are looking at $G(x,y)$ where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\dots,y_m)$ and trying to determine if each $y_j$ is a function of the $x_i$'s.  In other words, the implicit function theorem is trying to determine if one can write $y_j=y_j(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.  In your case above, $y$ might consist of a single variable instead of a vector.

In this setup, the $x_i$'s are independent variables, the inputs to the function.  Therefore, changing one of the $x_i$'s doesn't require a change in any of the other $x_i$'s.  Therefore, 
$$
\frac{dx_j}{dx_i}=0
$$
for $i\not=j$.  $x_j$ simply isn't a function of $x_i$ (unless $i=j$).

In your right-hand-side, I would not write $\frac{dy}{dx_i}$, the reason is that $y$ is meant to be a function of several of the $x_i$'s, so the derivative should be a partial derivative, and not a regular derivative.  The chain rule doesn't always end with a regular derivative, it depends on the dependence (and number) of the variables.